# Database size limitation in Lotus Notes 8.5 version

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

we have lotus notes database(.nsf) size of 94GB and working fine on opening  and searching for documents from LN client. But recently one of the database exceeded 64 GB and when we try to open the database from notes client, it alerting "Database exceeded maximum limit". So we have created a replica of db in the current version (Lotus notes 8.5) and after that database is opening fine from client. We have few more database which were nearing to size 64 GB (might have created in older version of notes).

Could some one please share inputs on what is the maximum allowable size for database(.nsf) file with DAOS disabled in Lotus notes8.5 environment.

Answer (score 3):

The database size limit in 8.5 is 64GB. However, it sounds like yoru database actually is smaller, but with view index it gets larger. So when you create a new replica, the view index is impty, until you start opening views... That is probably why it works (for now).
You can use Domino Administrator to look at the size of the view index in a database, and also to purge the view index for specific views.

In 9.0.2 (due out later this year) the view index (NIF) can be removed from the NSF and located in a different directory or even on a different drive.

Comment: Thank you for the input..from domino administrator i have checked the size of view index for database . Database-->Manage view ..i can see selected db size is 87.9 GB and view indexes of this database consume 112MB. database with size 87.9GB opening fine in LN 8.5 environment

Comment: And what was the result?  If the answer helped you, please accept it (and possibly upvote it).